# Hashmap in multithreaded environment when doing resizing

Tags: java, hashmap

I am following a tutorial and it basically explains about the cause of race condition which happens when resizing Hashmap in a multithreaded environment:

> In Java, if two thread at the same time found that now HashMap needs resizing and they     both try to resizing. on the process of resizing of HashMap in Java , the element in bucket which is stored in linked list get reversed in order during their migration to new bucket because java HashMap  doesn't append the new element at tail instead it append new element at head to avoid tail traversing. If race condition happens then you will end up with an infinite loop

I have two questions after reading this:

1. Why is the linked list for each bucket be reversed in order?
2. I can see there could be race condition, but cannot see how the infinite loop comes? Is it because one thread might append the element head to tail while the other doing it in the reverse order?

Please help me to clarify this, much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question - I just wanted to suggest that you use the thread-safe [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) in a multithreaded program.

Comment: `HashMap` is not thread-safe, it's a bad idea to use in multi-threaded environment. You will get a race condition either here on another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is at least one race condition related to *rehashing*. Look at this code fragment (it is from Sun JDK7):

```
boolean oldAltHashing = this.useAltHashing;
this.useAltHashing |= sun.misc.VM.isBooted() && (this.newCapacity >= Holder.ALTERNATIVE_HASHING_THRESHOLD);
boolean rehash = oldAltHashing ^ this.useAltHashing;
transfer(newTable, rehash);
this.table = newTable;
```

Here It is possible that thread T1 ends up with `rehash = true` and thread T2 ends up with `rehash = false` (let's suppose T1 has already changed the value of `this.useAltHashing`).

Now, guess that which thread will write the `this.table` - you have no idea, either can. So, it's a question of luck whether you get a consistent internal state or not.

Anyway, as I mentioned in my comment **by design, it is not supposed to use HashMap in a multithreaded environment**. It will not work. Either because of this, or because of other reasons. The above was just one example why **you shouldn't try to go against the contracts.**

Answer (score 9):

**The answer for your first question is in the quoted text:**

> "because java HashMap doesn't append the new element at tail instead it append new element at head to avoid tail traversing"

If HashMap would store them in insertion order it had to traverse the list at each insertion or store an extra pointer to the end of the list (and maintain it). Anyhow storing the elements in the bucket in insertion order would not give any benefits (at least I can't think of any).

**The answer to your second question relies here:**

http://mailinator.blogspot.hu/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the example is valid. What is clear is that it is implementation-specific. I think it also misses the bigger picture.

`HashMap`'s [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) clear states (emphasis theirs):

> If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.)

If you break the contract, all bets are off. The map is free to blow up in arbitrary, unspecified, ways.